# Is it possible to log into MySql server using linux users?

Tags: mysql, linux, settings

Is there a mechanism to tell MYsql server to accept username and passwords from the Linux server running it?

I have searched the web but almost all results are about how to use terminal to log into mysql?
is it possible to redirect the mysql authentication to shaddows files?

Comment: There is the [PAM auth plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pam-pluggable-authentication.html) but it appears to be Enterprise only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this line `plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so` into /etc/mysql/my.cnf file
2. restart server `sudo systemctl restart mysql`

Comment: Note this only works for local connections, and you still have to `CREATE USER` for each MySQL user you want to allow to connect.

Comment: DOes this work for Mariadb and MySql Community edition